# Mudar valores em Modal - C# MVC JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap, modal

Tenho o seguinte código javascript no meu projeto que pega os valores dos atributos quando o usuário clicar no botão de classe `rename` e chama um modal:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.rename').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var nome = $this.attr('data-name');
    var id = $this.attr('data-id');
    document.getElementById("nome_marca").innerHTML = nome";
    $('#id_marca').attr("value", id); 
    $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
});</script>
```

No modal, resumidamente, tenho a seguinte estrutura

Link que o usuário irá clicar na tabela para chamar o modal:

```
 <a class="rename" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" data-name="@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.nomeMarca)" 
                               data-id="@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.id)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit">
                                </span>Renomear</a>
```

Modal Header:

```
 <h4 class="modal-title">Digite o novo nome para a Marca <span id="nome_marca"></span></h4>
```

Form de renomear:

```
 <form method="post" id="form_rename" action="/Marca/RenomearMarca">
            <div class="modal-body">                    
                <div class="form-group">     
                    <input type="hidden" name="idMarca" id="id_marca" />                   
                    <input type="text" name="nomeMarca" required class="form-control" />
                </div>                    
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">                    
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Renomear"/>
            </div></form>
```

Quero que quando o usuário clicar no botão de classe `rename` ele pegue os valores dos atributos `data-name` e `data-id` e mande-os para o modal. Fazendo com que o span de id `nome_marca` seja mostrado, por exemplo, "Digite o novo nome para a marca [Asus]" e que o input `hidden` receba o valor do atributo `data-id`.

Eu já tentei de todas as maneiras mas os valores não estão passando. O que está faltando no código para funcionar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", ".rename", function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var nome = $this.data('name');
        var id = $this.data('id');
        $("#nome_marca").text(nome);  
        $('#id_marca').val(id); 
        $('#myModal').modal(); 
    });
});
</script>
```

Levando em consideração que o elemento clicado tenha os atributos data: name e id.

Sugiro que publique a parte do código de onde obtém esses valores também, aí fica mais fácil. (=

Comment: Olá Aline. Coloquei no código de onde está vindo o id e o nome. Coloquei do mesmo jeito que você me passou mas ainda não está setando os valores :S

Comment: Mostra pra gente o código do elemento com a classe: "rename", por gentileza, @RenanKaicLopes

Comment: Coloquei já na postagem. Verifica se atualizou aí para você

Comment: Troca essa linha:  $("#form_rename #nome_marca").text(nome); por  $("#form_rename #nome_marca").text("teste");  e me diga o que houve.

Comment: Fiz uma alteração no post. Teu h4 tá fora do form, isso? Então só remova o id do form qndo for passar o valor de text.

Comment: Exatamente Aline. Eu fiz as alterações conforme vc passou, mas não funciona :( não está passando para o modal. O mais estranho ainda é que pelo Fiddle o mesmo código FUNCIONA.

Comment: E tá entrando no evento de click? se tu colocar um debugger pára lá? ou um console log, imprime?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56593/discussion-between-aline-and-renan-kaic-lopes).